# How to change QLineSeries values?

Tags: qt, qchart

I want to use function which is changing `QLineSeries` values. And when it called first time everything is good. But when it called second time looping is working too long.

How to do this correctly?

```
    //...
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    ui_.chart->setChart(chart);
    ui_.chart->setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
    //...
}

void Wnd::setSeries(QLineSeries *lineSeries, const std::vector<double> &arr)
{
    lineSeries->clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        lineSeries->append(i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How much data are you saving?

Comment: More than 100 000.

Comment: enable the use of [opengl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-openglseries-example.html), `lineSeries->setUseOpenGL(true);`, also the problem is the data load, I would recommend using a QTimer to load data but that is little by little, for example a thousand data per call. They are a lot of data for a moment.

Comment: after `lineSeries->setUseOpenGL(true);` something from my desktop is painting in the chart. And it still working too long when it is called second time.